# How can give validation on custom registration form in drupal?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal-6, drupal-fapi, user-registration

I have created custom registration form in drupal 6. i have used changed the behavior of the drupal registration page by adding this code in themes. template file

```
function earthen_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    // tell Drupal what template to use for the user register form
    'user_register' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user_register', // this is the name of the template
    ),
  );
}
```

---

and
my user_register.tpl.php file is looking like this...

`//php tag starts from here

$forms['access'] = array(

  '#type' => 'fieldset',

  '#title' => t('Access log settings'),

);

 $form['my_text_field']=array( '#type' => 'textfield',

  '#default_value' => $node->title,

  '#size' => 30,

  '#maxlength' => 50,

  '#required' => TRUE

);`

```
<div id="registration_form"><br>
  <div class="field">
   <?php
        print drupal_render($form['my_text_field']); // prints the username field
   ?>
   </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); // prints the username field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); // print the password field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
      print drupal_render($form['account']['email']); // print the password field
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <?php
        print drupal_render($form['submit']); // print the submit button
     ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

How to make validation on "my_text_field" which is custmized.  
and exactly i want that as soon as user click on my_text_field then datetime picker should be open and whichever date user select, that date should be value in my_text_field.

so guys help.

Thanks in advance,
nitish 
[Panchjanya Corporation](http://www.panchjanyacorp.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's absolutely wrong.

You should use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) to alter forms. It doesn't belong in the theming layer.

To implement custom validation logic, use a [#validate callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#validate).

Comment: yes... i was trying to do on the core level now a days...i have first try on the theme level but it was not getting me the exact result....but thanks 4 replay.....

Comment: Hey Wim, I have put another question plz check it out.. now i had made module but now i want to add validation...so if you find any error then plz replay me... my question is on.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765193/validation-on-user-registration-form

Answer (score 0):

Really?

There are Drupal experts who say you can customize the form in the theme. See http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6